# generate list where element xn = f(xn-1)

Tags: r

I am wondering if the following code can be simplified in R (perhaps using apply, seq, etc.).  The intent is to create a time series of inflation indices where the index of any given year is the previous year's value, times a factor.

```
#i,l and r are the initial value, length and rate, respectively

    while (i<l){
      res<-c(res, (res[i-1] * (r + 1)))
      i<-i+1
    }
```

Comment: Bad code.  It's easy to mistake "ell" for "one".  Readability should be your second priority after correct behavior.

Comment: not helpful at all, see original question please

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for compound interest, you can simply generate a vector of indices for say the next 5 years (`0:5` because we include current year). Then we take a factor (5% or `1.05`) by which we want to increment our current value `100` each year, and use it in the exponentiation as the base to the vector of indices, which are the exponents:

```
# i*(1+r)^(0:l) becomes
100 * 1.05^(0:5)
# [1] 100.0000 105.0000 110.2500 115.7625 121.5506 127.6282
```